# How to have static file imported in js in assets directory while using webpack?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I have es6 angularjs app and this is in my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor",
        minChunks: function (module) {
            // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
            return module.context && module.context.indexOf("node_modules") !== -1;
        }
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {from: 'favicon', to: 'favicon'},
        {from: 'index.html'},
        {from: 'rpc.php'},
        {from: 'json-rpc.php'},
        {from: '.htaccess'}
    ])
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['env']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /jquery(\.min)?\.js$/,
            loader: 'expose-loader?jQuery'
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.(eot|woff2?|ttf|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

and my dist folder look like this:

```
448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2  e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf   index.html
89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg    f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot   json-rpc.php
app.js                                  fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff  rpc.php
dac34d70a97c4088841fb6f5f3d2df62.svg    favicon                                vendor.js
```

how can I make static files (loaded by file-loader) like fonts or svg files (one is from image imported in one of the files and one from bootstrap) in assets directory?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add `outputPath`:

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|woff2?|ttf|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader?outputPath=/assets/'
}
```

and also for webpack-dev-server I've needed to add:

```
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "serve": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
```

in package.json and in webpack.config.js:

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|woff2?|ttf|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader' +
        (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? '?publicPath=assets/&outputPath=/assets/' : '')
}
```